# Windows internals for starting large numbers of services

Tags: windows-10, performance, services, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

Does any one know the specifics of how Windows handles starting a large number of services that are independent of each other?

For example say I have one hundred non-trivial services that need to start but there is no hierarchy to them.  Will Windows try to start them all at once or is there built-in throttling to control how many are started at one time?  Is there a way to determine what the throttle limit is or is it dynamic based on system load?

Comment: Mark Russinovich wrote a pair of articles titled "Inside Win32 Services," which are still available. He outlines, among other things, how the SCM starts services.

Answer (score 0):

sc config [service name] depend=

That will set up service dependencies. You can also set delay times for startup. The command has documentation on all of those switches.